# Nib awakefromNib() crashes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class with a label and a collectionView, here is my code.

```
class CardSensors: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var botName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var viewModel: NewsFeedViewModel! {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "SensorCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil) 
        sensorsCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell")

        // Initialization code
    }

    func setUpView() {
        botName.text = viewModel.botName
    }

}
```

Obviously my cell has the correct Id and the correct reuse identifier. 
And when I try to call the nib like this.

```
let sensorView = CardSensors()
sensorView.awakeFromNib()
```

I get **`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`**. I tried to force the values but I always get some errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that viewModel is not nil?

Comment: You should not call `awakeFromNib` yourself. This should be called by the system after all the connections are made. As state by apple docs: "The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized ". You calling it will have the `sensorsCollectionView` being nil, since the archive was not loaded yet. Also, botName may be nil at the moment that the viewModel is set. Consider checking it before calling setupView, and re-call it on awakeFromNib if necessary.

Comment: I tried with the answer below but is not exactly working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned you should not call awakeFromNib() manually, it is something similar to how viewDidLoad() and viewWillAppear() get called automatically, the OS will fire it to let you know that your view has been loaded.

To initialize your view you could use the following static function, that allows you to call on the class to create a new instance of your CardSensors.

```
class CardSensors: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var botName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var viewModel: NewsFeedViewModel! {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }

    static func loadFromNib() -> CardSensors {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardSensors", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! CardSensors
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        sensorsCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell")
    }

    func setUpView() {
        botName.text = viewModel.botName
    }
}


let sensorView = CardSensors.loadFromNib()
```

Comment: Im getting this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle`

Comment: Make sure that your Nib names are correct and that your UINib file is added to the app target correctly

Comment: Yes, actually i put `CardSensors` and it was `CardSensor`

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't call awakefromNib by yourself because awakefromNib will be called after you init your view by using UINib or load Nib from Bundle.main.loadNibNamed.
You can fix your error by using this:

```
class CardSensors: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var botName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var viewModel: NewsFeedViewModel! {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }

    override init CardSensors() {
        super.init()
        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "SensorCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil) 
        sensorsCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell")

        // Initialization code
    }

    func setUpView() {
        botName.text = viewModel.botName
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do the sensorsCollectionView stuff in the init, it won't be initialized by then. Should be moved to awakeFromNib